# How to call tooltip on click not in hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Work with tooltip, and I want to show tooltip message on click, not in hover.

How it's possible to modify?

My code:

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 570px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="8" />
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
  <img src="~/images/help-80.png" />
  <span class="tooltiptext">
     <img src="~/images/keyboard.png" /><br />
     "This is the absolute maximum size of your item. Don't worry about different configurations here."
    </span>
</a>
```

So as you can see message open when you hover mouse in icon, but I want click and message stay opened.

Comment: The behaviour you're describing isn't clear

Answer (score 3):

You can check the style property and set the style on clicking on the image.

```js
$('.tooltip').click(function(){
  var el = $('.tooltiptext');
  el.css('visibility') == 'visible' ? 
    el.css('visibility','hidden') : 
    el.css('visibility','visible');
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 570px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="8" />
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="~/images/help-80.png" />
    <span class="tooltiptext">
        <img src="~/images/keyboard.png" /><br />
        "This is the absolute maximum size of your item. Don't worry about different configurations here."
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".tooltip").click(function(){
   $(".tooltiptext").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of showing `.tooltiptext` on `hover`, change it on `focus`.

```
.tooltip:focus .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

> But if you `focus` on the image from keyboard then also it will show
>   up. So, if you don't want that then there is only way i.e. let jQuery
>   handle it.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 570px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:focus .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="8" />
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
  <img src="~/images/help-80.png" />
  <span class="tooltiptext">
    <img src="~/images/keyboard.png" /><br />
    "This is the absolute maximum size of your item. Don't worry about different configurations here."
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS and remove  `visibility: hidden;` and also remove Class `.tooltip:hover .toolt` . Now show / hide your tooltip based on click.

```js
$('.tooltiptext').hide();
$('.tooltip').click(function(e) {
  $('.tooltiptext').show();
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 570px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="8" />
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
  <img src="~/images/help-80.png" />
  <span class="tooltiptext">
                                <img src="~/images/keyboard.png" /><br />
                                "This is the absolute maximum size of your item. Don't worry about different configurations here."
                            </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with bootstrap popover (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/). This will also give you the same result as you want.